# Invalid SQL Statement, Expecting SELECT

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @StartDate datetime = '[Start Date]', @EndDate datetime = '[End Date]'

SELECT ROWDATE, CALLID, DIALED_NUM
FROM oauser.CmsCallHistory 
WHERE DIALED_NUM IN ('6582000', '6752000')
  AND SEGSTART BETWEEN DateAdd(hh, -7, @StartDate) AND DateAdd(hh, -4, @EndDate) 
  AND sourceid = 1;
```

I have used this format in the past and it has worked fine, but now I am getting an error

> Invalid SQL Statement, expecting SELECT, etc

But I have a select statement.

Comment: This is a SQL Server query, not an Access (JET SQL) query. The two versions of SQL are very incompatible (and Access' SQL is positively ancient).

Comment: Is this perhaps a pass-through query but you forgot to assign the query's connection property?

Comment: @Jenna....you need to exposes more of the Context of your question.  Either you are soley in Access or Access is using SQL-Like statements against a MS-SQL database.

Comment: @Jenna...in essence the code-snippet you supplied is not compliant with current MS-Access SQL Syntax.  If you are running this from SSMS against MS-SQL, then this statement is a semi-correct statement.  But in MS-Access, even with Macros, this statement is non-compliant.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/1c9d5/2/0

Answer (score 2):

Right off the bat you are assigning text values to datetime variables....

Also that is SQL Server SQL not MS Access SQL. Not the same thing.

Comment: Actually you half-way correct....the PlaceHolders `[Start Date]` are Access capable syntax.  Otherwise, you are correct, the rest of the statement(s) are MS-SQL server compliant.

Comment: `[Start Date]` is Access capable syntax, `'[Start Date]'` is just a string. The analysis by Wolfgang Kais below is probably close to what is going on but I think some more information from the OP about what exactly they are trying to accomplish and in what environment is necessary for any more constructive help.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the format that you have used in the past and that has worked fine is something like this:

```
SELECT ROWDATE, CALLID, DIALED_NUM
FROM CmsCallHistory 
WHERE DIALED_NUM IN ('6582000', '6752000')
  AND SEGSTART BETWEEN DateAdd("h", -7, [Start Date]) AND DateAdd("h", -4, [End Date]) 
  AND sourceid = 1;
```

You did for sure use this in MS Access, and when opening the query (displaying a datasheet), Access did ask you for help, specifying what the values of `[Start Date]` and `[End Date]` are (because Access can't handle these expressions all by itself).

Now (thanks to my skills in clearvoyance), you were sitting in front of an SSMS window and trying to "migrate" your experience to the next level, an MS SQL Server database. Since your square brackets were underlined red, you declared variables and after enclosing the brackets in single quotes, the red lines disappeared (yay!)... been glad too early. With SQL Server, assigning quoted strings to datetime variables will work, but only if these strings can be converted to a datetime value. Unfortunately, `'[Start Date]'` isn't a candidate for that. And, since Microsoft created SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) mainly for "managing" a database, they did not make SSMS that clever (end-user-friendly) to interprete the square brackets as parameters and create little pop-up windows to ask a user for the values. SQL Server itself has no graphical user interface, it can only receive SQL commands, process them and return results. That's what you probably found out, so you copied the code from SSMS back to Access... but Access wants a query to start with a SELECT (or UPDATE etc.) statement. Access can't execute arbitrary T-SQL code.

Conclusion: You will have to either let Access process the query and display parameter pop-ups like in the past (meaning that you must use the Access syntax), or you must find a way to pass the parameter values to SQL Server using pass-through queries or/and VBA Code (if at all using MS Access).

(Hoping that I'm not totally wrong)